# Why is mounted nas showing 0 inodes on users partition?

Tags: nfs, disk-usage, ext4, btrfs, nas

I am using a NetGear ReadyNAS machine as a NAS for our server. The server is a linux CentOS 6.6. The server is run using Rocks cluster, with all our users' home directories located on the NAS. My understanding is that the home directories are automounted to /home when a user logs on.

Recently we have been facing the infamous, intermittent 'no space left on device' error while our drive is nowhere near full. It is not a case of full virtual memory either. Yet, the issue usually gets resolved (temporarily) after deleting or compressing some files. I'd like to check if my inodes are full but for some reason the share where our user directories are located does not report inodes information and shows only 0's. Could someone please explain why this is the case, and how I can check the inodes on this share of my NAS?

The NAS is a nfs file system in a RAID 10 configuration, while my linux cluster uses ext4. Below is output of `df -h` performed on our master node:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2              20G   16G  2.5G  87% /
tmpfs                 7.9G   12K  7.9G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             190M  103M   78M  57% /boot
/dev/sda6             4.7G   12M  4.5G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda3              12G  2.0G  9.0G  18% /var
tmpfs                 3.9G   63M  3.8G   2% /var/lib/ganglia/rrds
nas-0-1:/nas/nas-home/user1
                   15T  8.4T  6.3T  58% /home/user1
nas-0-1:/nas/nas-home/user2
                   15T  8.4T  6.3T  58% /home/user2
```

and `df -i`:

```
Filesystem            Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda2            1281120 365426  915694   29% /
tmpfs                2057769      4 2057765    1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1              51200     50   51150    1% /boot
/dev/sda6             320000    797  319203    1% /tmp
/dev/sda3             768544  20175  748369    3% /var
tmpfs                2057769    596 2057173    1% /var/lib/ganglia/rrds
nas-0-1:/nas/nas-home/user1
                       0      0       0     - /home/user1
nas-0-1:/nas/nas-home/user2
                       0      0       0     - /home/user2
```

Now if i `ssh` into the nas itself and repeat, here is the output of `df -h` performed on the nas:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             10M  4.0K   10M   1% /dev
/dev/md0        4.0G  578M  3.1G  16% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           2.0G  5.9M  2.0G   1% /run
tmpfs           978M  1.5M  977M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md127       15T  8.4T  6.3T  58% /nas
/dev/md127       15T  8.4T  6.3T  58% /home
/dev/md127       15T  8.4T  6.3T  58% /apps
/dev/md127       15T  8.4T  6.3T  58% /var/ftp/nas-home
```

and `df -i` performed on the nas:

```
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev           499834   446 499388    1% /dev
/dev/md0            0     0      0     - /
tmpfs          500472     1 500471    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          500472   593 499879    1% /run
tmpfs          500472    22 500450    1% /run/lock
tmpfs          500472    15 500457    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md127          0     0      0     - /nas
/dev/md127          0     0      0     - /home
/dev/md127          0     0      0     - /apps
/dev/md127          0     0      0     - /var/ftp/nas-home
```

The share on my nas in question is /nas, why is it shown to contain 0 inodes?

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer. This problem has been driving me nuts and hindering our work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NAS is probably using a filesystem which doesn't use static inode tables.  The most notable modern examples of such filesystems are BTRFS and ZFS, but most newer filesystems use dynamic inode allocation, and many (including BTRFS) have opted to just not report anything for inode usage because it just doesn't matter (since running out of inodes means your out of space on the filesystem itself, so you couldn't create a new file regardless).

Comment: You are right. When I ran `mount` on my master node, it reported my nas as being of `type nfs`. However this is probably due to the network access to the nas being set to nfs protocols. After ssh'ing directly onto the nas and running `mount` it reveals the nas in fact uses btrfs file system. Shortly after this discovery I learned the real cause of our 'device memory full' error to be full metadata which can be solved by running a balance.